# How to prevent button from moving while text is changing?

Tags: ios

I have an issue with a button next to a textfield, when the text in the text field is changing, the button is moving accordingly. How can I prevent this from happening?
A picture as I'm not sure I made myself clear:
[image]

In the cell "Amy" the minus sign in not aligned with all the other as the text is different. How can I prevent this moving?

Comment: I think you can set `label.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .horizontal) = 1000` for the label that has the name. In this case "Amy" label.

Comment: you need to fix the width of the `UILabel` to the max it can take e.g. `888` and make it's text alignment centre

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to solve this, but the most straight forward is to not constrain to an element's edge that's changing position.

One solution would be to put a width constraint on that textfield showing the "10"/"0" text so it doesn't grow and make your - button reposition. It looks like you could also set the - button's trailing constraint to be the number textfield's ***trailing*** constraint (**not** it's leading constraint) plus a constant.

I'd probably just make that number field a fixed width with a constraint, though, and leave your current "- button trailing" to "number field leading" constraint as is.